# Is it possible to show the current time on the start screen in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

This customization would be nice. Is this possible out of the box, and if not, could a developer modify the start screen to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Clock` tile  : http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/clock-tile/0ccf24f9-d2ab-4d3c-82be-53049fadeb04

`World Time` tile : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482779/World-Time-Clock-a-Windows-8-Ap

Someone also mentioned `The Time` by Jeff Key. Here is a page that talks about it.
http://win8review.com/apps/app/The-Time-Jeff-Key-e0f4831b-d6ac-481d-ad94-88e2bb6efe10

Answer (score 6):

[Clock Tile](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/clock-tile/0ccf24f9-d2ab-4d3c-82be-53049fadeb04) is a Windows Store app which lets you see the time on the start screen in Windows 8 using the live tile feature:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is an app called [The Time](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-in/app/the-time/e0f4831b-d6ac-481d-ad94-88e2bb6efe10) by Jeff Key in the app store.

Have a look at the top left tile. You can switch between the small and large tile view.
[image: The Time]

Comment: Download Link ?

Comment: @Root How do I get the link from the app store?

Comment: @VenkatH One way is to click on the Share charm and select Mail. It should generate the link in the message body.

Comment: @Louis That didn't work. The link was truncated with ellipsis and it didn't expand to show the whole link nor could it be clicked on.

Comment: @VenkatH Yeah, you're right. I guess this way requires actually mailing it to your self.

Comment: @Root I've added the link.

Answer (score -2):

This is currently not possible, no. I'm fairly sure this isn't even programmable due to security reasons.

Comment: You forget Live Tiles ;)

Comment: Smart indeed :)